# browser RUM stats going to ELK or Influx

Tags: javascript, elastic-stack, instrumentation, influxdb

Has anyone found a way/approach to collect the RUM statistics such as from Boomerang https://github.com/SOASTA/boomerang, Bucky Client http://github.hubspot.com/BuckyClient/, or similar javascript metrics collector and sending the information back to the origin hosting server to then pass to ELK or Influx for analysis/visualization?

There are a lot of other alternatives, but nothing around standardizing to ELK or Influx  (The Bucky Server may be interesting, but we don't currently host Node.JS servers, only tomcat and IIS).

Thanks for any thoughts/expertise on RUM metrics to ELK or Influx!